# go looping channels, but missing an index

Tags: go

When looping over a channel, I would like to get an index - to be able to add to an array.

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
)

func main() {
  tasks := []string{"foo", "bar", "baz"}
  results := process(tasks)

  for result := range results { // index?
    fmt.Println(result) // I would like to add result to an array of results?
    // newresults[index] = result???
  }
}

func process(tasks []string) <-chan string {
  ch := make(chan string)
  go func() {
    for index, task := range tasks {
      ch <- fmt.Sprintf("processed task %d: %s", index, task)
    }
    close(ch)
  }()
  return ch
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For example,

```
i := 0
for result := range results {
    fmt.Println(result)
    newresults[i] = result
    i++
}
```

Comment: I guess :-) Why would I ever ask. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Aternatively to peterSO's answer, you can simply use `append` to add to the end of your slice.

Comment: I thought of that, but it will give a performance penalty - right? As it will have to internally loop through each time. That is why I will add to an array of results.

Comment: @ChrisG.: what do you mean by "internally loop through each time"? Append needs to make a copy when it allocated a larger underlying array, but that's not every time. If you pre-allocate the capacity, it's equivalent to assigning by index anyway.

Comment: I thought that the copying, that append is doing would make some kind of loop.

Comment: you can do: make([]string,0,len(tasks)) which pre-allocates the storage.  then when you results = append(results,result), no re-allocations occur

Answer (score 1):

Channels do not have an index. If you want to track the count, create your own count variable and increments within the for loop.

The alternative is to create a struct with a index and the task name.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Task struct {
    Index int
    Task  string
}

func main() {
    tasks := []string{"foo", "bar", "baz"}
    results := process(tasks)
    myresults := make([]*Task, 3)

    for result := range results { // index?
        fmt.Println(result) // I would like to add result to an array of results?
        // results[index] = result???
        myresults[result.Index] = result
    }
}

func process(tasks []string) <-chan *Task {
    ch := make(chan *Task)
    go func() {
        for index, task := range tasks {
            t := &Task{Index: index, Task: task}
            ch <- t
            // ch <- fmt.Sprintf("processed task %d: %s", index, task)
        }
        close(ch)
    }()
    return ch
}
```